# Using WebKit.NET to call a C# function from JavaScript

Tags: c#, webkit

I have been playing around with webkit.net in a c# win forms project, and love how easy it is to call JavaScript functions from within the C# program with:

`browser.Document.InvokeScriptMethod("functionName", new object[]{"parameter1", "parameter2"});`

Now the question is how to do this the other way round... Is there some sort of event listener that can listen for a javascript function call, or any way to invoke a c# method via the JavaScript running in the webkit browser?

The way I'm doing it at the moment it using a bad hack ... having a look at the available event listeners, I hooked up to the `TitleChanged` event, and read the value of a hidden `input` field in the html .... this is really bad and needs an actual solution.

Thanks in advance,
 - Greg.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webKitBrowser1.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(Form1_Navigating);
    }


    private void Form1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = e.Url.ToString();
        if (url.IndexOf("app://") > -1)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            processRequest(url);
        }
    }
```

This may not pass your Ugly Hack test, but is an ancient method for processing requests from a .net embedded browser.   Essentially you intercept a URL GET request in the browser.  If the URL contains a keyword (such as app://), you cancel the GET and process the URL parameters.  Returning a value, was traditionally accomplished by calling the Navigate Method, however, using the method you described in your post, you can just directly call a javascript function.

Answer (score 5):

There is a fork on github that adds the support for this with a scripting object (works similar to standard winforms browser). When the browser loads you can set the scripting object, the class that will handle your js calls, by using webKitBrowser.ObjectForScripting = myObject. Then from js you can call the method by using window.external.foo(). Hope this helps.

Comment: guess it would help if I included the link :) https://github.com/scampy/webkitdotnet

Comment: can anyone find a successfully compiled version of webkitdotnet with this enabled? Thanks.