# using webkit.net to call javascript method from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, webkit.net

from this question [Using WebKit.NET to call a C# function from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146687/using-webkit-net-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript).

I have been using a version webkit.net and the version I have does not do anything when calling callWebScriptMethod (to test I have used the same code with Forms.Webbrowser and that works). So first of all the version I have callwebscriptmethod does not work.

From the same link above I used the following link https://github.com/scampy/webkitdotnet.
Which has a webkit.net version were ObjectForScripting is working so I can use javacript to call c# but can not call c# from javascript as callwebscriptmethod is not implemented.

Does anyone know of a webkit version and a link of were I can get a version with both options implemented.

Regards Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function is possible by using .GetScriptManager.CallFunction("name", new Object[] { arg1, arg2, ... }); if yoiu are using .NET 4. If you want to use .NET 2 you can use .StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("name(arguments)")