# Calling a C# function from Java Script for the Webkit Browser and .NET 20

Tags: c#, javascript, open-webkit-sharp

I have to call a C# function from Java Script in an embedded Webkit browser (OpenWebkitSharp). For .NET 4.0 this can be easily done with:

```
<webkitbrowser>.GetScriptManager.GlobalContext.GetGlobalObject().SetProperty("CallbackHandler", new CallBackhandler());
```

Unfortunately .NET 40 crashes my application and I'm looking for a way, to do this in .NET 20 (Visual Studio 2005).

Any ideas?

Tom

Comment: Have you considered a call to a self-hosted WebAPI controller?

Comment: @RichBryant: Thank you for this advice, but I looked for a way to do this more directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for a solution on this issue.

After intensely searching the web, I found a solution that is working for me:

[Using WebKit.NET to call a C# function from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146687/using-webkit-net-to-call-a-c-sharp-function-from-javascript)

http://phil-rashleigh.blogspot.de/2012/10/calling-c-from-javassript-for-local.html

Tom